# How do you create a FacesMessage from a class that is not a JSF Bean?

Tags: java, jsf

I am new to JSF and struggling with a problem. I am hoping that someone can help me.

Problem:

- A handler that is not a bean detects a message from a TCP/IP pipe.
- The handler needs to create a new `FacesMessage` to display the message in a message box.
- Since the handler is not a bean, `FacesContext` returns `null`, therefore the handler cannot write the `FacesMessage`.

Questions:

1. Is it somehow possible to do what I am trying to do?
2. What is the best way to propagate an external message from a Java class that is not a bean to a `FacesMessage` so that it is displayed on the UI?

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() method only returns a valid faces context if you're in an actual faces session. I think what you should be looking at doing is architecting this such that your class that does the TCP/IP message handling provides a means for a faces managed bean to get information about the messages to the front end, and then accessing that method from a managed bean.

Depending on what type of application server you're using, you may want to set this whole thing up to interact through an EJB session bean. But really any backing bean or faces logic should absolutely be separate from logic unrelated to your UI.

If you're using a JEE6 compliant application server (like Glassfish) you could set up an @Singleton EJB to hold a set of messages (be sure to use a data structure that supports concurrency) and something like JCA-sockets (http://code.google.com/p/jca-sockets/) to handle the socket communication.

Comment: Yeah...I was thinking of using a Singleton bean and then doing a JNDI lookup of that bean and calling addMessage which in turn uses FacesContext but that bean also returns null for the FacesContext?

Comment: The singleton bean is different from a JSF backing bean. While they're both called beans, they're not quite the same thing. The EJB/JEE layer is separate from the view layer for JSF. What you'd end up doing is injecting your singleton into a backing bean (you'd use the XML descriptor Rachel described to set up the backing bean or you can set it up using annotations)

Comment: Ok, I don't think that is going to work and here is why:  1 - My handler code is the one that detects the event and it is not a bean.  2 - My handler code is the one that needs to somehow propagate the message to the UI.  3 - My handler code has no access to a bean at that time.  So, there is no bean to inject into another bean in this case as there is no request being processed.  The handler code in step 1 above is just a thread that detects and event.

Comment: You may want to make your handler code lookup a JMS message queue and then send messages to an MDB to get it into your application server if you object to turning your handler into a bean. Or you could communicate with your application server through a webservice... Either way you need to do something to get it to be available to the JSF front end.

Comment: I can turn my handler into a bean but I don't think that is going to solve anything as my code that detects an event has no request - it is a thread that is running in the background and detects an event. So, if I pass in my bean as a handler and try to get a FacesContext from it, I think I am going to have the same issue again which is the FacesContext is null because I am not doing any JSF processing at that time.

Comment: Would it be possible to do an internal post from the handler to an HttpServlet, and then have the servlet get the FacesContext and create the FacesMessage?

Comment: The FacesContext can only be associated with a faces request. So you could make a request to a faces page and do it that way if you wanted to... Maybe you could create an application scoped managed bean and manipulate values in that through requests to a JSF page? It still feels a bit wrong to do it that way, but that is a way you can get what you want.

Comment: I ended just using the handler as is and then using the <p:poll> functionality to check the value of the counter in the handler. When the value in the counter increases I then fire off a method call in  one of the beans to create the JSF message.

Comment: I wish I could have used Prime Faces push to do this instead of poll as poll is problematic - it never stops running!  But I am using GlassFish and I've read elsewhere the PF push doesn't work on GlassFish right now.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible, alternative way is to create backing bean either by `@ManagedBean` annotation or by having entry in faces-config.xml like

```
  <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>bean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.test.bean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

and now you can get `facesContext` and create `FacesMessage` both, hope this helps.

Comment: Hmmmm, my problem is that my handler cannot be a bean so I don't have the choice of converting it to a bean so I can do that.  Is there any other way to display a message from an external Java class to a JSF UI?